# When trying file download it shows error route not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is in my blade file

```
{!! Html::link(storage_path().'/documents/'.$file->name, $file->name) !!}
```

This is controller

```
public function download($file_name){
    $file_path = storage_path('documents').'/'.$file_name;
    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('documents/{file}','FilesController@download');
```

Comment: Take the `storage_path` out of your `HTML::link`

Comment: can you write that into an answer so that I can give you upvote and for finding solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add your exact route to your HTML link instead of the path of the file:

```
{!! Html::link('/documents/'.$file->name, $file->name) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of using `HTML::link()` is like this:

```
{{ HTML::link(storage_path().'/documents/'.$file->name, 'Download Link')}}
```

and this would produce the HTML like this:

```
<a href="the_generated_link_here">Download Link</a>
```

> See more about [HTML::link()](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/186/generating-a-html-link)

You can also use [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route) helper method like this:

Just add a `name()` method in-front of the route method, as it gives route a common name.

```
Route::get('documents/{file}','FilesController@download')->name('downloads.link');
```

HTML should look like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('downloads.link') }}">Download Link</a>
```